# Custom Rounding Function in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Let's say you have a formula that produced the following numbers:

```
50.77%
24.62%
24.62%
```

Added together they equal 100%, however they do not want the decimal places shown, and the number still visually showing they equal 100%. If you take the decimal places out you get 51% 25% 25% which actually equal 101%.

They suggested that I put some type of formula that will round the largest decimal place up.. ie... 50.77% becomes 51%, and round the others down... if it goes over 100%, if it is still not equal to 100%, round up the next largest number until and so on until the total does equal 100%.

Anyone know what type of formula of vba coding that I could use for this?
I do not even know where to start.

Comment: without having any layout, it is hard to give an answer... at least, there is no built in function in excel, this way you need to do it yourself with a proper function... however, to directly round it will make it harder, because you would need to check every formula in every cell... but you also could replace the last formula to `1-[all cells which count for this]` to always get 100%...

Comment: @DirkReichel - I was thinking the same thing. But the danger of this approach is that in more complicated cases you could end up with a negative value in the last cell (e.g. 98.5%, 0.5%, 0.5%, 0.5%)

Comment: In these cases I tend to find that the solution lies in formatting that hides the excess digits; since Formatting doesn't edit the cell values the sum will remain unchanged.

Comment: If an executive can't look at numbers and understand that they're rounded and that the total that's calculated *does* add up to 100% even though they're adding up to 101% on the printout, ....nothing can help. Doing what you suggest amounts to **making the formula calculate WRONG NUMBERS** just so some exec can have the satisfaction of adding up numbers to 100% in their head. If they don't understand rounding and decimals, they shouldn't be looking at reports all day.

Comment: Either they can have the numbers rounded, or they can have the numbers add up exactly. They cannot have both.

Comment: Before folks ask why your Managers are asking for something so quirky/weird/"wrong", let's not forget the [Peter Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_principle). :P

Comment: I do not disagree with you.  This is regarding Demand, Inventory and Turns.  I would think that they wanted absolute correct numbers with the decimal if need be.  To me accuracy would be important, but they are telling me different.  I informed them that excel is setup to be accurate not a flyby night quest answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use helper columns with this formula:

```
=IF(SUM($B$1:B1)+ROUND(A2,2)>1,1-SUM($B$1:B1),ROUND(A2,2))
```

[image]

Comment: That's excellent! Except next, the executive starts asking why 24.62% rounds up to 25% on row 3 and down to 24% on row 4. I still think it's better to educate the reader than to make funky calculations that throw off the numbers - especially if these numbers are used anywhere in further calculations. Good job on coming up with a single formula that does it though!

Comment: @Mat'sMug I agree 100.01% with you.  Math is Math.  If the execs can't understand rounding then the need to go back to school.  I was just trying to give the poor schmuck something that they could use.  I have bosses like this and it drives me crazy.  I have told a few they need to make up their minds, which way they want it.

Comment: @cinstanl please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.  It is something only you can do.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, you can do: `=TEXT(SUM(A1:A3),"##")`, assuming your numbers are in `A1:A3`.

Comment: But the exec will grab their calculator and add up the individual cells manually and say "here, Excel is wrong!"

Comment: @Mat'sMug - How so? Yes, it should total `100.01`, but if the Exec. wants rounded numbers, my formula will show `100`.  ...or did I not get what you're saying?

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do in cases like this is to set a formula at the last number (e.g. A4) like this one :

`=1-(SUM(A1:A3))`

Edit:
This is what I do, if I have to use vba:

1. Calculate the whole range. Round each number as you wish.
2. See the difference which you should add or substract (e.g. if you get the sum 
   to 99.9%, then your difference is 0.01).
3. Add this difference to the last number in the range. Via VBA.
4. Even if it is negative, (e.g. if you have a sum of 100.01) then you should sum with a negative number, thus anything is ok.

Comment: so you basically do the same like what is written in the very first comment?

Comment: The sum result would need to be rounded to the displayed number of decimals before being subtracted, but yeah, this. And it's so wrong to have to do this.

Comment: @DirkReichel you are right. Anyway, to come up with something more productive, see edit.

Comment: I tried the first formula and it gives me the answer of 1 for each one.  I need the formula to show:  for example... 50.77 rounded up to 51%, 24.62% rounded up to 25% and 24.62 in the third column rounded down to 24%.

Comment: The post regarding the vba coding, I'm not sure how to even start the vba coding.  If I am understanding you.. you would put a code in place to do the normal rounding and if the sum of the numbers, with the decimal place equals 100.01%.  Where would I put the difference so it is showing the ending numbers (without decimal places) are equivalent to 100%. The difference needs to be spread out so that it is showing on the cells that are being added.  For example.. 50.77 would be 51%, 24.62, would be 25%; and the last 24.62 would show as 24%.

Answer (score 0):

The only I can think of is "cheating" in a really nasty way... assuming that you have formulas, which do the calculation, a replacement is not possible... So I simply change the formatting (and keep the old values) like this:

```
Private Sub recalc_percs()
  Dim RangeToCheck As Range
  Set RangeToCheck = Range("A5:A9") 'designet to work with a range containing only 1 area and 1 column
  Dim x(1) As Variant, i As Long, b(2) As Double
  RangeToCheck.NumberFormat = "0%"
  x(0) = Evaluate(RangeToCheck.Address & "*100")
  x(1) = Evaluate("INDEX(ROUND(" & RangeToCheck.Address & "*100,0),)")
  While Application.Sum(x(1)) <> 100 And Abs(100 - Application.Sum(x(1))) < 4 'the <4 is for deleting or whatever to not loop endless times
    For i = 1 To RangeToCheck.Rows.Count 'get highest and lowest difference
      b(0) = x(1)(i, 1) - x(0)(i, 1)
      If b(0) < b(1) Then b(1) = b(0)
      If b(0) > b(2) Then b(2) = b(0)
    Next
    If Application.Sum(x(1)) < 100 Then b(0) = b(1) Else b(0) = b(2)
    For i = 1 To RangeToCheck.Rows.Count
      If b(0) = x(1)(i, 1) - x(0)(i, 1) Then
        x(1)(i, 1) = x(1)(i, 1) + (0.5 + (b(0) > 0)) * 2
        Exit For
      End If
    Next
  Wend
  For i = 1 To RangeToCheck.Rows.Count
    If Application.Round(x(0)(i, 1), 0) <> x(1)(i, 1) Then
      RangeToCheck.Cells(i).NumberFormat = """" & x(1)(i, 1) & "%"""
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

It may need to change some parts... but basically it is working. Also it is not looking very well, but I am in a hurry right now... sorry.

If you have any questions, just ask... I'll reply as soon as possible ;)

Comment: The answer that Scott provider above does the trick and does not require any VBA coding.   Thanks Scott

Comment: I asumed that furmulas are not what you desired... however... if you got your answer then it is fine and I don't need to rewrite my answer ;)